# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID_ and CrtIsValidHeapPointer assertion errors after int main() return stmt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I get the following assertion errors **after the control passes the return statement**:

- _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
- CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

while trying to run this code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Customer.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
Queue q1;
Queue q2(3);
Queue q3(5);

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    Customer c(i);
    bool in = q1.enqueue(c);
    if (i <= 9 && !in)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: default size is smaller than 10!!" << endl;
    }
    else if (i > 9 && in)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: default size is bigger than 10!!" << endl;
    }
}
q1.print();
cout << "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ***********" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Customer el = q1.dequeue();
    if (i != el.getId()){
        cout << "Error: dequeue order is not correct!!";
    }
}
cout << endl;

Customer underflow = q1.dequeue();
if (underflow.getId() != 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR: underflow not taken care of!!" << endl;
}

Customer c1(12, "moni");
if (!q3.enqueue(c1))
{
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 3!!" << endl;
}
Customer c2(14, "mobi");
if (!q3.enqueue(c2)){
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 3!!" << endl;
}

Queue q4(q3);

if (q3.dequeue().getId() != 12)
{
    cout << "ERROR: cdequeue should return the first element in line (12)!!" << endl;
}

if (!q4.enqueue(21)){
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 4!!" << endl;
}

if (!q4.enqueue(7)){
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 4!!" << endl;
}

if (!q4.enqueue(332)){
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 4!!" << endl;
}

if (q4.enqueue(12)){
    cout << "ERROR: add element number 6 to queue with size 5 (q4)!!" << endl;
}

q4.print();
cout << "12 14 21 7 332 ***********" << endl;
q3.print();
cout << "14 ***********" << endl;

q2.print();
cout << "queue is empty! ***********" << endl;

q2 = q3;
q2.print();
cout << "14 ***********" << endl;

if (!q2.enqueue(17)){
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 2!!" << endl;
}

if (!q2.enqueue(18)){
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 2!!" << endl;
}

if (!q2.enqueue(3521)){
    cout << "ERROR: cannot add element to queue 2!!" << endl;
}

q2.print();
cout << "14 17 18 3521 ***********" << endl;
q3.print();
cout << "14 ***********" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef _QUEUE_H_
#define _QUEUE_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Customer.h"

class Queue {
private:
Customer *elements; // Holds the elements of this queue.
int mSize; // Size of the queue
int mTop;  // Index of the last element in the queue.

public:
static const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;

// Default constructor
Queue() : mSize(DEFAULT_SIZE), mTop(-1) {
    elements = new Customer[DEFAULT_SIZE];
}

// Copy constructor
Queue(const Queue &q) : mSize(q.mSize), mTop(q.mTop) {
    elements = new Customer[mSize];
    for(int i = 0; i <= mTop; i++){
        elements[i] = q.elements[i];
    }
}

// Initialize a new Queue with the specified size.
explicit Queue(int size) : mSize(size), mTop(-1)  { 
    elements = new Customer[size];
}

// Add the given Customer to the end of the queue.
// Returns true if the Customer was added, false if the Queue is full.
bool enqueue(Customer);

// Remove the first Customer from the Queue.
// Returns the Customer that was removed.
Customer dequeue();

// Print the IDs of the Customers in this Queue in the order 
// in which they will be attended.
void print() const;

~Queue() {
    delete[] elements; 
}
};

#endif
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to define an assignment operator for Queue, so the destructor ended up trying to delete the same array twice.

Answer (score 0):

Took a quick look so but I think the problem is somewhere in your implementation of `bool enqueue(Customer)`.

When you do the following:

```
    Customer c(i);
    bool in = q1.enqueue(c);
```

what is happening in `enqueue`?  Is a copy of Customer being made properly?

Not specifically an answer but I think this will drive you in the right direction or perhaps you can post the code for `Customer`?